# I can delete a file from a read-only directory on a samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, cifs

I have this line in `/etc/fstab` (`//freenas/share/` is a samba share, the samba-share user has the ACL permissions to modify stuff)

```
//freenas/share /run/media/myname/freenas/share cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/myname/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,perm,uid=myname,gid=myname,setuids 0 0
```

I created a directory `/run/media/myname/freenas/share/test_dir/` and a file `/run/media/myname/freenas/share/test_dir/test_file`
Then I made the directory and the file read-only:

```
chmod a-w test_dir
chmod a-w test_dir/test_file
```

If I try to edit the file with `nano test_dir/test_file` I can't save any changes I do. If I try to delete the file (`rm test_dir/test_file`) then it asks me if I want to delete a read-only file, I type `yes`, press enter and the file gets removed.

If I try to remove the protected directory ('rm -rf test_dir/') it doesn't work: `rm: cannot remove 'test_dir/test_file': Permission denied`, same if the directory is empty `rm: cannot remove 'test_dir/': Permission denied`.

At some point, it also said `touch: cannot touch 'test_dir/test_file': Permission denied` after I tried to create a new file. However, I cannot replicate this behavior (I now can create new files no matter what permissions I have and what files are already in the directory).

EDIT: On the server, I configured ACLs so that a user `a` can modify the share. On the client machine (i.e., on the machine I tried all these things I described) I am logged in as a local user with name `myname`, and in `~/.smbcredentials`(which I used to mount the samba share' I have set the `password=1234` (`1234` being the password for user `a`) and `user=a`.
I thought that I could apply posix permissions by adding these arguments to the fstab line: `perm,uid=myname,gid=myname,setuids` so that locally on my client machine I can edit permissions and have them enforced locally.

How can I configure stuff so that this file can't be removed if the parent directory is read-only?

Comment: Are you doing this as the Samba user? Are the ACLs configured on the Samba server.

Comment: On the server, I configured ACLs so that a user `a` can modify the share. On the client machine (i.e., on the machine I tried all these things I described) I am logged in as a local user with name `myname`, and in `~/.smbcredentials`(which I used to mount the samba share' I have set the `password=1234` (`1234` being the password for user `a`) and `user=a`.